# Wrong port on redirection Rails application running on Nginx + Thin server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, port, thin

I am having Rails application running on Nginx + Thin server on port 3037. 
This is testing server.

When I perform redirection in rails application, for example to **domain.com:3037/users** it redirects me to  **domain.com/users**, port 80.

I can solve this by setting port like this **users_url(:port => 3037)** , but I can't do it for every redirect link. I believe there exist easier way to solve this problem.

This is nginx config file:

```
upstream dev_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9297;
}
server {
  listen 3037 default_server;
  server_name www.domain.com:3037;
  root /full_path_to_project/public;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://dev_server;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add your Nginx config file?

Comment: @ali-sepehri-kh just added it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by rewriting nginx configuration file as it was done in this link: http://blog.mohitkanwal.com/blog/2013/04/10/deploying-rails-on-nginx-and-thin/. Here is how my configruation file looks like:

```
upstream dev_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9297;
}
server {
  listen 3037 default_server;
  server_name domain.com:3037 www.domain.com:3037;
  root /full_path_to_project/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
  }

  location @ruby {
    proxy_pass http://dev_server;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can set host header of Nginx to keep your port:

```
upstream dev_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9297;
}
server {
    listen 3037 default_server;
    server_name www.domain.com:3037;
    root /full_path_to_project/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dev_server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port; # Keep your request port
    }
```